# A sequence with exactly four accumulation points

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that this example I came up with, namely the sequence $$a_n=\cos\left(\frac{\pi n}{3} \right)$$
Has exactly $4$ limit points/accumulation points?

Is equality fine for accumulation points is basically what I am  asking.

I  also was thinking of an example with infinitely many accumulation points and wondered if the same example would cut it:

$$b_n = n \cos(n) $$
Since it oscillates back and forth it comes back to every single point eventually.

---

EDIT:

I asked this question again as I had made a mistake in asking my question, I meant to have $\cos(\frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{\pi n}{2})$ I was not allowed to edit this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

- $n=1 \implies a_1=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\frac12$
- $n=2 \implies a_2=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)=-\frac12$
- $n=3 \implies a_3=\cos\left(\pi\right)=-1$
- $n=4 \implies \ldots$

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot the halfturns, basically I just wanted the numbers on the unit circle corresponding to $ \pm\frac{1}{2}$  and $ \pm\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3}$ I apologise for my error.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Ah ok, I fix accordingly!

Comment: you helped me find the error though

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo I can update the answer if it can be useful.

Comment: I will make a new question because people want the question to stay the same.

Comment: @WesleyGroupshaveFeelingsToo Ah ok! Thanks